# Ubuntu 15.04 and Windows 8.1

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

I have successfully installed Ubuntu 15.04 alongside Windows 8.1 and everything is great, Grub asks which OS I want to boot to and everything, until I select Windows 8.1 as the OS to boot to.

I'm not saying that Windows no longer works, just the opposite. I can boot to Windows just fine, but when I reboot and want to go to Ubuntu, nothing works. The screen goes blank for about 15 seconds then I get a message stating that a file is missing and gives the file path as

> ```
> \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
> Status: 0xc000007b
> ```

I am completely new to Ubuntu.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Comment: Answered my own question. I changed the UEFI (BIOS) settings to boot to Ubuntu first which bypassed the Windows Boot Manager which was causing the problems to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem myself.

I changed the boot order in UEFI (BIOS) to boot to **Ubuntu first** and that solved the problem.